# What's the portable way of checking whether a long type data is in range of int?

Tags: c++

For example:

```
long xx = ..;  //is xx in range of an int type?
```

I came up w/ with this question in my mind, so it's not really an interview question, as some of you may ask.

Basically I want to write the code to check it w/o using `<climits>`, e.g., `INT_MIN`, `INT_MAX`. What's the portable, most effective way to do it, if not impossible?

By portable, I mean it shouldn't be implementation defined or platform dependent, e.g., a byte is not always 8 bits.

Comment: Would comparing `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)` work?

Comment: Then their ranges are not the same.

Comment: Then how do you know if a long-type xx is in range of int? I'm not asking if the range of long is in the range of int. Instead, it's: whether a particular long type data is in the range of int type;)

Comment: When `sizeof(int) == sizeof(long)`, the ranges of `long xx` and `int yy` are the same; when `sizeof(int) != sizeof(long)`, the ranges of `long xx` and `int yy` are not the same.

Comment: I did, several times. What part do you think I missed?

Comment: @dasblinkenlight The OP is not asking whether `int` and `long` are the same size. He's asking whether a variable of type `long` can be safely casted down to `int`. In other words, "Does this `long` fit into an `int`?".

Comment: @Mysticial Oh, I see, I did not realize that the OP was talking about *values* of variables fitting in the range of `int`, not the variables themselves.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <limits>

long xx = 5432;

if(long(numeric_limits<int>::max()) > xx)
{
    int x = static_cast<int>(xx);
    //...
```

Answer (score 1):

Why not go strainforward?

```
long v = 1; 
bool in_range = (int)v == v;
```

Comment: IIRC, a signed integer cast that goes out of range is implementation defined behavior. I'm still trying to find the source for this though...

Comment: For a value of `1` I'd expect this to be true every time.

Comment: @Lol4t0: If sizeof(long) > sizeof(int), converting a long to int may be implementation-defined.  ---C++2003 4.7 Integral conversions

Comment: But if value, converted to int coniside with unconverted, it means that value can be saved with variable of type int (captain Obvious says so). And why should we care, how it is converted?

Comment: Implementation defined could be "raise a signal by the processor".

Comment: Implementation-defined? The compiler can even put your bank account in that data, if it wants.

Comment: @EricZ As long as it documents it.  The C standard is more specific: the allowed behavior is either an implementation defined value, or an implemention defined signal is raised.